# Result gets \n while converting bytes to base64 String

Tags: android, string, base64, byte

I am trying to convert bytes to base64 String and in the resultant string i am getting **\n**, how can i get base64 result without these escape sequences, i know i can remove them from the string but the point is why does it ad these extra characters.

That's how i am converting my bytes to base64 string

```
/*
 * Convert bytes to Base64
 */
public static String convertBytesToBase64(byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(Base64.encode(bytes, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Base64.NO_WRAP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64) Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line).

```
public static String convertBytesToBase64(byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.NO_WRAP));
}
```